# facingMode property not working in react-qr-scanner in react js

Tags: reactjs

In one of my react js application, I need to integrate QR scanner.
I am using **react-qr-scanner** npm library (version 1.0.0-alpha.7 to be specific).

The issues I am facing is:

1. Default front camera is only working and I am not able to use rear camera for scanning.
   I have used property: `facingMode="rear"` but this is not making any difference.
2. I am not able to list available camera options to select from. Any help in this would be appreciated.

Below is example code snippet:

```
<QrReader
  facingMode="rear"
  delay={500}
  style={styles.previewStyle}
  onError={handleError}
  onScan={handleScan}
/>
```

Library reference URL is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-qr-scanner.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue an i solved like this:
react-qr-scanner (v1.0.0-alpha.11)

```
<QrReader delay={delay} onError={handleError} onScan={handleScan} constraints={{
  audio: true,
  video: { facingMode: "environment" }
}} />
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use modern-react-qr-reader Instead react-qr-scanner because react-qr-scanner has the bug.

Comment: The npm package was last published three years ago.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

```
<QrReader
delay={ 300 }
style={ {width: '100%'} }
onError={ handleQRError }
onResult={ handleScan }
constraints={ {facingMode: 'environment'} }/>
```

`"react-qr-reader": "^3.0.0-beta-1",`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: your response is for "react-qr-**reader**" while the original question is regarding "react-qr-**scanner**". They are two different libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It works only with https

```
<QrReader
    key="environment"
    constraints={{
    audio: false,
    video: { facingMode: "environment" }} 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a read...

Value
An object based on ConstrainDOMString specifying one or more acceptable, ideal, and/or exact (mandatory) facing modes are acceptable for a video track.

An exact value in this case indicates that the specified facing mode is specifically required; for example:

You can use

```
const constraints = {
  facingMode: {exact: "environment" },
};
```

This indicates that only a user-facing camera is acceptable; if there is no user-facing camera, or the user declines permission to use that camera, the media request will fail.

The following strings are permitted values for the facing mode. These may represent separate cameras, or they may represent directions in which an adjustable camera can be pointed.

"user"
The video source is facing toward the user; this includes, for example, the front-facing camera on a smartphone.

"environment"
The video source is facing away from the user, thereby viewing their environment. This is the back camera on a smartphone.

"left"
The video source is facing toward the user but to their left, such as a camera aimed toward the user but over their left shoulder.

"right"
The video source is facing toward the user but to their right, such as a camera aimed toward the user but over their right shoulder.

reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/facingMode